# Brighter irregular edge of a Polaroid photo

Tags: polaroid

I use Polaroid OneStep 2 with Color i-Type film packs.

Sometimes, at the bottom edge of the image, not fully developed irregular areas appear as the medium inside has not been properly distributed. Only the bottom edge is a problematic one, the rest of the photo is fine.

It does not seem to be related to the temperature the photos were taken in. Also, it has been happening with multiple packs, so it might not be the case either, I think. I try to keep the rollers clean every time I insert a new one.

What may be the cause of that? Below you can find a photo of the issue I’m talking about. See the bottom edge of the pictures, especially the second one.

[image: polaroids]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I posted this question, I've been trying a few things. It seems that the problem is solved for now. These are my observations about this issue and possible ways to prevent it:

- I keep camera's rollers clean – they are cleaned every time when I change the pack,
- since I use OneStep 2, the film shield is used. I wait a moment until I take the photo out and hide it to a pocket, bag, backpack, depending on the temperature outside,
- it might be related with the film package storage, I don't store them in the fridge,
- I never shake the images, so this is not the case,
- I don't take pictures quite often – maybe the medium 'stagnates' in some way or is exposed to the same conditions as the camera,
- after the photo is taken, I am trying to hide it in my pocket upside-down, so the rest of the developing medium can flow down.